# DateTime format missing in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2007

I'm facing a problem in Excel which is the date's values are all missing in the cells.

Actual values in database:

```
ID  Date
001   2015-05-18 00:00:00.000
002   2015-05-22 00:00:00.000
003   2015-05-21 00:00:00.000
004   2015-05-18 00:00:00.000
```

Excel view (ERROR):

```
ID  Date
1   00:00.0
2   00:00.0
3   00:00.0
4   00:00.0
```

Comment: Format in the Date column is "General". I export the data as CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel doesn't recognize "-" as valid date seperator. You have two options:

- change your locale to allow "-" as a date seperator
- convert the "-" to your local date seperator (usually a '.' or "/") when creating / querying the data source

Comment: **locale**: Control Panel / Region & Language / Additional settings / (temporarily) set (short) date format to "yyyy-MMM-dd" (I do this usually for one-off's) ... **query**: reformat date fields into strings recognized by Excel using functions like TO_CHAR() [Oracle], DATE_FORMAT() [MySQL], etc.

Comment: sorry yes ... as month is numeric it must be **MM** - my bad! Just tried here ... I can import a CSV with the OP's exact format if I tweak the locale beforehand ... and this is not about EXCEL ... the locale is set at the OS level (==> control panel) and EXCEL just "benefits" from that. And here both OS (WIN7) as well as Excel 2010 understand MMM as 3-letter abbreviated month ... though in Excel you must define it maybe as a Custom format - depending on your underlying locale.